# Finding min values and indexes from a matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
|  1 3  5 |
|  2 4 -6 |
| -3 -5 7 |
```

I would like to compute the minimum of each row and the indices of that min values, such as:

```
| 1  |
| -6 |
| -5 |
```

and the indexes

```
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
```

Is that possible without using a loop? I have tried with cv::reduce but I need the indexes. Thank you so much,

Comment: Which language? C++? Python?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why it is so important not have loops at all? Single loop that applies minMaxLoc on each row of matrix will be efficient and simple.

Comment: OpenCV can optimize loops if you compile it with the TBB library, so I was wondering if I could do it with an OpenCV method in order to optimize it.